# Load Test using Coded UI scripts : How to run a coded UI script in Load test for multiple users

Tags: performance, performance-testing, load-testing, coded-ui-tests

We are working on a project, where the ask is to find the end to end response time of a windows application (client rendering + server).

We are able to achieve this for a single user thread, by running a coded UI script in load test.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms318554(v=vs.100).ASPX

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468125(v=vs.110).aspx

But since coded UI test drive the mouse and keyboard we will be able to have a single virtual user running at a time per test agent.

How can we run the same coded UI scripts with multiple virtual users?

I have heard that in HP Load Runner, multiple virtual user can be used to execute a UFT / QTP scripts in Performance Center / controller by using Terminal services.

Answer (score 1):

John, you can try using [ZebraTester](http://www.zebratester.com/) and record the script for this test. The trial version allows you to have up to 20 Virtual Users and these can run multiple loops depending on the length of your test. The same tool can record the script as well as run the load test from your local machine.

[image]